# Visual Studio 2010 Load Testing: MySQL as results repository

Tags: mysql, sql-server, load-testing

I have some load tests using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I've tried to store results in SQL Server Express, but it has DB size limitaion. Is there any way to use different database as results repository, MySQL for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**

Because the load test result repository is a TSQL script located here (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE). During a load test, Visual Studio or Test Controller will invoke stored procedures in the repository. After a load test, VS will also exec sp to get results. So, it's impossible because VSTS don't know how to call something else.

However, the limitation of Sql Server Express 2012 is around 10 GB. Do you really reach limitations  in your test ? Try to limit collected logs and counters (change sampling interval ?). Sometimes, statistics are enough.

In addition, you can try [export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385895.aspx) results for backup.